# $L^p(\mu)$ space relations

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $(X,M, \mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $1 \leq p < r \leq \infty$.

Suppose $f \in L^p (\mu) \cap L^r(\mu)$. Show that $f\in L^s(\mu)$ for $p \leq s \leq r$.

Attempt:

Suppose $f \in L^p (\mu) \cap L^r(\mu)$. Then $\int |f| ^p d\mu < \infty$ and $\int |f|^r d\mu < \infty$.

Isn't it obvious that $\int |f|^s d\mu < \infty$ already?

I'm bit confused on what to show.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: $f=f\chi_{|f| \leq 1}+f\chi_{|f| >1 }$

Comment: If you think it’s obvious then explain why? When I’m  marking homework places where the student said it’s ‘obvious’ are often the places they missed the point and lose marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Proposition 6.10 in Folland: If $0< p <q<r \leq \infty$, then $L^p \cap L^r \subset L^s$ and $\|f\|_s \leq \| f\|_p^{\lambda}\|f \|_r^{1- \lambda}$, where $\lambda \in (0,1)$ is defined by $\lambda = \frac{s^{-1} -r^{-1}}{p^{-1} - r^{-1}}$ when $r \ne \infty$, and $\lambda = p/s$ when $r \ne \infty$.

When $r= \infty$, you use the definition of $\| f\|_{\infty}$ to show the inequality.

When $r \ne \infty$, it's just Holder's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done from the Hölder inequality, in the form:
If $1/\alpha+ 1/\beta = 1$, then

$$
\int |FG|\;d\mu \le
\left(\int |F|^\alpha\;d\mu\right)^{1/\alpha}\;\left(\int |G|^\beta\;d\mu\right)^{1/\beta}
\tag1$$

Given $p<s<r$ and $f \in L_p \cap L_r$ as in the problem, let
$$
\alpha = \frac{r-p}{r-s},\quad \beta = \frac{r-p}{s-p}
\quad\text{so that}\quad \frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta} = 1\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{p}{\alpha} + \frac{r}{\beta} = s,
$$
and let
$$
F = |f|^{p/\alpha},\qquad G = |f|^{r/\beta}
$$
Plug into $(1)$ to get
$$
\int|f|^s\;d\mu \le \left(\int |f|^p\;d\mu\right)^{(r-s)/(r-p)}
\;\left(\int |f|^r\;d\mu\right)^{(s-p)/(r-p)} < \infty.
$$

---

We will need a different (easier) argument in case $r = \infty$.

Comment: Oh wow this is clever. I've always wondered if Holder would work for this as well but did not have the patience to figure out the exponents to make it all happen.

Comment: I found the formulas for $\alpha, \beta$ by solving the two desired equations for $\alpha,\beta$

Comment: Additional remark.  This argument shows something stronger:  The function $s \mapsto \log \|f\|_s$ is a convex function.

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* obvious and it is to some degree but it requires a small amount of work to get there. Kavi's comment almost completely gives it away. If $|f(x)| \le 1$, then $|f(x)|^s \le |f(x)|^p$ since $p < s$. Similarly if $|f(x)| > 1$, then $|f(x)|^s \le |f(x)|^r$ since $s < r$. Can you put these together to show that $\int |f(x)|^s \,d\mu(x) < \infty$?

This is called ($L^p$) interpolation for what it's worth and is a very useful technique in functional analysis.

Comment: There is a stronger inequality one can prove which I thought was called Lebesgue interpolation (write $1/s=(1-t)/q  +t/r$ and apply Holder). Or maybe they are equivalent after a scaling argument